# Can I make a Bash script permamnetly alter its own code?

Tags: bash, shell-script

For example I want this line to be in my bash script

```
versionNumber="4.10"
```

I am then using a wget to check the version number against a website and if the two differ then I want my script to continue grabbing the new version and setting it up, but I want the script to permanently alter `versionNumber="4.10"` to now be `versionNumber="4.11"` so the next time it is ran there will be no update. Currently the versionNumber is sitting in a txt file but I'd like to have this all contained in 1 file if possible.

Comment: Use can use `sed -i s/^versionNumber=.*/versionNumber=4.1.1/ scriptname` to make the  change to the script.

Comment: "Setting it up" implies installing something. If something is installed, it probably records the version somewhere, right? Does the script actually have to contain the version number at all?